# How do I make local scheduled notifications on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

Good afternoon.
The essence of the app: on the specified date and time, the app must "throw out" local notifications with certain phrases. The phrases don't overlap, so you won't be able to repeat them.
How do I set a separate time and date for each keyword?
I'm new to Swift. I try to understand. But after googling already porridge in my head.
According to the tutorials, I have now made a code that works, but it works on a delay of 10 seconds. That is, after clicking on the button in 10 seconds, the push is thrown.
How do I make it so that either I just set different delays(for example, 3,6,9,12,15 hours for each keyword), or rebuild the code to separate each notification?
I don't even have to have it all at the click of a button. You just log in to the app, accept a request for notifications, and they come by the hour.
The question may seem very stupid. Don't judge strictly. Attached the code.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func sendNotification(sender: UIButton){
    scheduleNotification(inSeconds: 10) {(success) in
        if success {
            print("We send it")
        } else {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
}

func scheduleNotification(inSeconds seconds:TimeInterval, completion: (Bool) -> ()) {

    removeNotification(withIdentifiers:["Bear"])

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: seconds)
    print (Date())
    print(date)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Текст"
    content.body = "Текст"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Bear", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

}






func removeNotification(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String]) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
}

deinit {
    removeNotification(withIdentifiers: ["Bear"])
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that instantiates all the notifications you need then send it through iteration.

```
func prepareAndSendLocalNotifications() {

    // Prepare your notifications

    let oneHourNotifContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    oneHourNotifContent.title = "One hour"
    oneHourNotifContent.body = "It's been one hour since you logged in"
    oneHourNotifContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    oneHourNotifContent.userInfo = ["timeInterval": 3600, "identifier": "Bear"]
    // The key is to use the userInfo of the notification content to pass anything you need

    let twoHourNotifContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    twoHourNotifContent.title = "Two hours"
    twoHourNotifContent.body = "It's been two hours since you logged in"
    twoHourNotifContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    twoHourNotifContent.userInfo = ["timeInterval": 7200, "identifier": "Wolf"]

    // Create a list of them
    let localNotifList: [UNMutableNotificationContent] = [oneHourNotifContent, twoHourNotifContent]

    // Iterate to send all of them
    localNotifList.forEach { (notification) in
        scheduleNotification(notification: notification)
    }
}

func scheduleNotification(notification: UNMutableNotificationContent) {

    // Get the value for "timeInterval" key.
    guard let timeInterval = notification.userInfo["timeInterval"] as? Double else { return }
    guard let identifier = notification.userInfo["identifier"] as? String else { return }

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeInterval)

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notification, trigger: trigger)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("There was an error trying to send \(notification.title) notification")
        }

        print("Successfully sent \(notification.title) notification")
    }
}
```